# Data binding in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I passed data with MAT_DIALOG_DATA in console shows that data are passed but in my dialog, I don't see the name.

Here is the `code` maybe it will help.

```
 <input placeholder="" matInput [(ngModel)]="data">
```

This is in .ts format.

```
 @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, )
```

This is in dialog when click edit to show me the name on that input placeholder

Comment: Are you sure data is a primitive value like string or number? And not array or object?

Comment: I open the dialog like this.

     openprojecteditdialog(project): void {
    console.log('', project)
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ProjectEditDialogComponent, {
    data : {
            projects: project ? project.name : ''

    }
  });
  }

And in my dialog I inject data like i wrote in my question.

Comment: So data is an object. If you want to show the name in the input you need to bind with property. For example: [(ngModel)]="data.projects.project.name" (depends on the structure of your object)

Comment: @MateuszWitkowski thank u it works